# How to mock UserManager<IdentityUser>

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, moq, xunit

I am trying to work out how to add unit testing to my project.  I thought it was best to start with a blank project and work it out from the start rather than adding it to my main project.  Once I understand the process i figure i can start refactoring my project for adding testing.

## web application

So i created a web application and added default user identity to it.

This gave me a start up looking like this

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
        {
            // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
            options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => true;
            options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;
        });

        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(
                Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));
        services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();

        services.AddMvc().SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_2_1);
    }
```

Then i created a simple controller and passed the usermanager in the constructor.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class SweetController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public SweetController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }
    public async Task<int> NumberOfGummyBearsForUser(string userId)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        var userHasASweetTooth = await _userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, "SweetTooth");
        if (userHasASweetTooth)
        {
            return 100;
        }
        else
        {
            return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

### Unit Test

The first thing i have been trying to do is mock this user manager but its not working.

```
public void Test1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var mockUser = new Mock<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();
        var userManager = new UserManager(mockRepo.Object);  <-- error here see image below

        var controller = new SweetController(userManager.Object);

        // Act
        var result = await controller.NumberOfGummyBearsForUser("123");

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(100, result);
    }
```

The error looks like this

[image]

I think i need to pass more to create this usermanager object but i am not sure what all the tutorials i have found use ApplicationUser and not IdentityUser so i am at a loss as to how i can mock this object.

Comment: Can't you just pass `var userManager = mockRep.Object` as it is a mock of userManager?

Comment: [`MockHelpers`](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/test/Shared/MockHelpers.cs#L15) from the Identity tests themselves might be a good reference point here.

Comment: It's not clear why you want to `new` up `UserManager<T>` when `UserManager<T>`  is what you **want** to mock?

Comment: @Tseng well I am not sure either as i said i am trying to learn how to do this i am following https://alastairchristian.com/mocking-asp-net-identity-2-usermanager-methods-b740c703b580   If you have a better way of doing it please feel free to add an anwser

Comment: `mockUser` is already a mock of the `UserManager<T>`. You pass it to the **controller** (obviously you want to test the controller, **NOT** the UserManager, ASP.NET Core Identity team did that already for you :P

Comment: @Tseng i want to test that the controller returns the correct response.   I am no trying to test the usermanager i am trying to mock the user manager so it can be passed to the controller.

Comment: Hence you don't need to `new` the `UserManager`. A mock inherits the user manager and overrides its methods to test (only non-sealed, virtual or abstract method and properties. Sealed or non-virtual/non-abstract won't work)

Comment: @KirkLarkin thanks for that link think that will be extremely helpful

Comment: I would also suggest checking out aspnet example: https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/master/test/Identity.Test/UserManagerTest.cs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just do

```
// Arrange
var mockUser = new Mock<UserManager<IdentityUser>>();

var controller = new SweetController(mockUser.Object);
```

You don't need

```
var userManager = new UserManager(mockRepo.Object);  <-- error here see image below
```

at all. `mockUser` is already the mocked `UserManager<T>`, which you place a mocked instance via `mock.Object`.

When you mock an object you don't have to instantiate it with all of its dependencies (that would be integration test), that's the point of mocking (along with making methods return a desired value and do behavior tests to make sure your tested code has called a specific method with specific parameter of the mocked object).

Of course per se the above code won't work, since you didn't setup any test conditions/returns for `FindByIdAsync` and `IsInRoleAsync`. You have to setup these with

```
mockUser.Setup( userManager => userManager.FindByIdAsync(It.IsAny<string>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(new IdentityUser { ... });
mockUser.Setup( userManager => userManager.IsInRoleAsync(It.IsAny<IdentityUser>(), "SweetTooth"))
    .ReturnsAsync(true);
```

Then whenever the mock is called it returns your predefined user and a predefined result.

Comment: Ok that works, guess i was over thinking.  Any tips on getting data into the usermnager so i can test on it?

Comment: You don't get any data "into" the manager, you setup conditions (like the ones above). When a method "IsInRoleAsync`is called with **any** user and "SweetTooth" as 2nd parameter, it returns true. The point of the mock is that you dont need to fully initiallize the mocked object, instead you just tell: "Return this value, when something is passed or called". No code inside UserManager<T> is ever called  when mocking (except if you enable  calling of base classes, but that wont work in most cases due to the not fully initialized class)

Comment: Did you try and run this?  I am getting "Castle.DynamicProxy.InvalidProxyConstructorArgumentsException"  when i run the test

Comment: No, I'm at work :P See Kirkins linked comment, you need to pass the constructors matching parameters to the mock options, since the first one can't be null it has to be a mock itself: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/test/Shared/MockHelpers.cs#L19-L26 you can directly reference it (if you dont mind the extra dependencies in your test project) or just do it the same way. Alternatively use something like [AutoMoq](https://github.com/darrencauthon/AutoMoq) (Autofac moq extensions)

Comment: On a second though, Automoq wont help you with moq dependencies, had a similar issue some time ago

Answer (score 6):

With Tseng's help I got this working.  A fully working version of this is

## controler

```
   private readonly UserManager<IdentityUser> _userManager;

    public SweetController(UserManager<IdentityUser> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public async Task<IdentityUser> GetUser(string userId)
    {
        var user = await _userManager.FindByIdAsync(userId);
        return user;
    }
```

## Test

```
[Fact]
    public async Task Test1()
    {
        // Arrange
        var store = new Mock<IUserStore<IdentityUser>>();
        store.Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync("123", CancellationToken.None))
            .ReturnsAsync(new IdentityUser()
            {
                UserName = "test@email.com",
                Id = "123"
            });

        var mgr = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(store.Object, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

        var controller = new SweetController(mgr);

        // Act
        var result = await controller.GetUser("123");

        // Assert
        Assert.NotNull(result);
        Assert.Equal("123", result.Id);
    }
```

I removed the role check just to get it working as basic as possible.

Comment: I wonder why this multi-parameter constructor works and not the solution by @Teng