# Moq usermanager missing IUserEmailStore

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, moq, xunit

## what i am testing.

This is an identity server project with a login to federated gateway.  I do not control this gateway and am having issues with them not returning the proper claims back to me that i need to verify the users logins.  I would like to be able to test that i can handle these errors.

For example email claim is missing without that i can not login a user.

I have created a test that tests the email claim is missing returns an error.(Works fine)

Now I am trying to test the other side of things.  If the claims are in fact there it should return the user that matches to the claims returned.

## The method we are testing

```
public static async Task<(ApplicationUser user, string provider, string providerUserUserName, IEnumerable<Claim> claims, string message)> FindUserFromExternalProvider(AuthenticateResult result, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, ILogger<SegesExternalController> logger)
    {
        var externalUser = result.Principal;

        // try to determine the unique id of the external user (issued by the provider)
        var eMailClaim = externalUser.FindFirst(SegesSettingsConstants.SegesEmailClaimName);

        if(eMailClaim == null) return (null, null, null, null, $"{SegesSettingsConstants.SegesEmailClaimName} claim not found.");

        // remove the user id claim so we don't include it as an extra claim if/when we provision the user
        var claims = externalUser.Claims.ToList();
        claims.LogSegesClaims(logger);

        claims.Remove(eMailClaim);
        // Should we remove more claims
        var provider = result.Properties.Items["scheme"];
        var providerUserUserName = eMailClaim.Value;

        var user = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync(providerUserUserName);  // Test Breaks here

        return (user, provider, providerUserUserName, claims, null);
    }
```

## Test

```
[Fact]
public async void Federated_login_with_email_claim_return_no_error()
    {
        // Arrange

        var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal();
        principal.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(
            new Claim[] {
                new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name", "Testbruger til André"),
                new Claim("http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/windowsaccountname", @"PROD\Salg43"),
                new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/postalcode", "8200"),
                new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/locality", "Aarhus N"),
                new Claim("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/emailaddress", "test@email.com"),
            },
            "FakeScheme"));
        var authenticateResult = AuthenticateResult.Success(new AuthenticationTicket(principal, new AuthenticationProperties() { Items = { { "scheme", "fed" } } }, "FakeScheme"));


        var exprectUser = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "test@email.com",
            NormalizedUserName = "TEST@EMAIL.COM",
            NormalizedEmail = "TEST@EMAIL.COM",
            Email = "test@email.com",
            Id = 123,
            EmailConfirmed = true
        };

        var mockEmailStore = new Mock<IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        var mockQueryableUserStore = new Mock<IQueryableUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();

        var mockUserStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
        mockUserStore.Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync(exprectUser.Id.ToString(), CancellationToken.None)).ReturnsAsync(exprectUser);
        var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(mockUserStore.Object, null, null, null,  null, null, null, null, null);


        var logger = new Logger<ExternalController>(new LoggerFactory());

        // Act
        var (user, provider, providerUserUserName, claims, errorMessage) = await AuthorizationHelpers.FindUserFromExternalProvider(authenticateResult, userManager, logger);

        // Assert
        user.ShouldNotBeNull();
    }
```

## The issue with above.

I am trying to moq a usermanager for my unit test

```
var exprectUser = new ApplicationUser()
        {
            UserName = "test@email.com",
            NormalizedUserName = "TEST@EMAIL.COM",
            NormalizedEmail = "TEST@EMAIL.COM",
            Email = "test@email.com",
            Id = 123,
            EmailConfirmed = true
        };

var mockUserStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
mockUserStore.Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync(exprectUser.Id.ToString(), CancellationToken.None)).ReturnsAsync(exprectUser);
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(mockUserStore.Object, null, null, null,  null, null, null, null, null);
```

however when the method i am testing tries to find the user.

```
var findUser = await userManager.FindByEmailAsync("test@test.com");
```

it throws an error

> Message: System.NotSupportedException : Store does not implement IUserEmailStore.

How do i implement IUserEmailStore in my moq usermanager?

My unit test project does contain the newest EntityFramework package.

Trying another way.

```
var founduser = userManager.Users.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Email.Equals("test@test.com", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

results in

> System.NotSupportedException : Store does not implement IQueryableUserStore.

I think i must be moqing this wrong.

### Update From comment

Ok i can moq the IUserEmailStore but I am not sure what i should do with it

```
var mockEmailStore = new Mock<IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>>();
```

Comment: Mock [`IUserEmailStore<TUser>`  Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.iuseremailstore-1?view=aspnetcore-2.2) which is derived from `IUserStore<TUser>`

Comment: Ok and do what with it?  var mockEmailStore = new Mock<IUserEmailStore<ApplicationUser>>();

Comment: Thing is that you would need to know how the manager accesses that dependency in order for you to setup a safe path to the expected behavior. However I believe this might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). What  are you actually trying to test? For what do you need the manager?

Comment: What @Nkos saidi: Why do you want to test the UserManager. Microsoft did get a good amount of work into testing it and covering its implementation with unit tests. Its not your task as a consumer of the library to unit test the libraries implementation. You should unit test **your own code**, not code from **others**

Comment: I am testing that the claims that were returned for the user were missing.  I am testing my own code this is my own method that processes claims returned by a federated gateway login.

Comment: But user manager is not your code, its the code from Microsoft. Your test cases are flawed when you need to test other peoples code. And if you don't trust that Microsoft did it right, maybe use another library or file an issue if you have a corner case which you think may be a bug?

Comment: @DaImTo Looks like you may need to reword this question to show the actual problem. Also it appears that your code is tightly coupled to 3rd party dependencies that make it difficult for you to test it in isolation.

Comment: @Nkosi your right i have created a nice wall of text for you guys I hope it helps you understand what i am trying to test.   I appreciate the help

Comment: imho that doesn't seem to be an issue with any code you or others have written, just that it depends on the actual values set/configured in the database, which isn't a thing you want test with neither unit nor integration test). Sounds more like a use case for an acceptance test (where you fully spin up your application against a staging environment, with database and all dependencies) and do a request to a specific endpoint and observe the result (aka black box testing). Why I think so? Cause claims are returned for a given user, when they are assigned in the database, that how identity works

Comment: In case of IdSrv4, its determined via the `apiclaims`/`clientclaims`/`identityclaims` which claims are or are not included in the token or the principal (in addition to ASP.NET Cores `aspnetroleclaims`/`aspnetuserclaims` tables). The ASP.NET Core claims a re added to the user when he logs in on the Identity Provider and the other (IdSrv tables) are for when the token is generated / introspection endpoint) - or you add it in code via custom implementation of `IProfileService` in IdSrv4 (this ones is called when the claims are requested (token creation or userinfo endpoint) )

Comment: Remember this is a federated gate way login.  This is not logging in though my identity server directly.  When you use federated login my identity server is more or less just a pass though to the third party login server  if their login server does not return the proper claims my identity server needs to be able to handle it.

Comment: Still sounds like a use case for an acceptance test. How are unit/integration tests helping you verify results of a library written by a third party, where the result depends on an external source? All your test (in the attempt started in the question) would be to tell you "claims are returned when they are sent by the third party source or database", which Microsoft (very likely) already covered in their Unit tests against `UserManager<T>`. Do you know what I mean?

Comment: If you would have extended `UserManager<T>` and did override some of its methods or added new ones, then thats a different case to do a unit test against this new version of `MyUserManager<T>` to ensure the changes do what they are supposed to do. But your tests aim against the unchanged `UserManager<T>` implementation

Comment: @DaImTo if the goal is to isolate the testing of the logic contained within your `FindUserFromExternalProvider` method under test, then I would suggest abstracting out the dependencies the you do not control so that you have more flexibility to test your logic. The main issue here is implementation concern contained with the `UserManager<TUser>` that is making it difficult for you to test in isolation.

Comment: I am still learning how testing works i am not sure i understand what you are talking about at this point @Nkosi give me a few more months.   I am gong to be doing a lot of refactoring on this project i suspect.

Comment: @DaImTo yeah, it is a design concept. all part of having SOLID code that is easy to maintain and test. Read up on SOLID principles. Your tests are just revealing the issues associated with the design of system. Tests have a habit of revealing bad code design.

Answer (score 2):

I managed to create a full moq usermanager that lets me search on email

```
 public class MoqUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public MoqUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser> userStore) : base(userStore,
                new Mock<IOptions<IdentityOptions>>().Object,
                new Mock<IPasswordHasher<ApplicationUser>>().Object,
                new IUserValidator<ApplicationUser>[0],
                new IPasswordValidator<ApplicationUser>[0],
                new Mock<ILookupNormalizer>().Object,
                new Mock<IdentityErrorDescriber>().Object,
                new Mock<IServiceProvider>().Object,
                new Mock<ILogger<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>>().Object)
        { }

        public override Task<ApplicationUser> FindByEmailAsync(string email)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new ApplicationUser { Email = email });
        }    
    }
```

which gives me

```
var mockUserStore = new Mock<IUserStore<ApplicationUser>>();
mockUserStore.Setup(x => x.FindByIdAsync(exprectUser.Id.ToString(), CancellationToken.None)).ReturnsAsync(exprectUser);
var userManager = new FakeUserManager(mockUserStore.Object);
```

So now i can verify that the proper user is returned from my identity server matching the federated login user.

Comment: That can work too. Glad you were able to figure something out.

Answer (score 2):

Okay your with the updated question the issue lies in

```
var userManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(mockUserStore.Object, null, null, null,  null, null, null, null, null);
```

This is not creating a mock, but an actual instance of `UserManager<T>`.

You will have to do

```
var userManagerMock = new Mock<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>(mockUserStore.Object, null, null, null,  null, null, null, null, null);
```

then do an setup

```
userManagerMock.Setup(um => um.FindByEmailAsync("test@email.com)).Returns(exprectUser)
```

and pass `userManagerMock.Object` to your

```
var (user, provider, providerUserUserName, claims, errorMessage) = await AuthorizationHelpers.FindUserFromExternalProvider(authenticateResult, userManagerMock.Object, logger);
```

When mocking, you never want to call `new` on the external dependency and instead mock it, since then you can't change its behavior for a specific test. `UserManager<T>` should have all or most public properties as virtual, so you can override them.

Comment: Which you should have know actually, you edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55412776/how-to-mock-usermanageridentityuser/55413067#55413067) too :P Also see [this source](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/release/2.2/src/Identity/test/Shared/MockHelpers.cs#L19-L26) on how Microsoft creates Mock instances of UserManager (user store is required, since there is a null-check in the constructor)